# Question about Menus on Wordpress

Tags: menus

I have a question regarding something that is not working properly, I have a menu that is not working, currently with my theme I have 10 menus, one being the main nav and the rest are needed for special purposes, the thing is, the main one is not working, is taking the menu values from one of the other menus, but I'm sure I'm referring that menu in the right way.

In my header I'm calling my menu like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main', 'menu' => 'menu_center' )); ?>
```

And in my `functions.php` I have this:

```
add_theme_support('nav-menus'); 
if ( function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'main' => 'Main Nav',
        /* FOOTER MD USA */
        'footer-opinion' => 'Footer Opinion',
        'footer-noticias-economicas' => 'Footer Noticias Economicas',
        'footer-consumo' => 'Footer Consumo',
        'footer-empresas' => 'Footer Empresas',
        'footer-noticias-actualidad' => 'Footer Noticias de Actualidad',
        'footer-suplementos' => 'Footer Suplementos',
        'footer-finanzas' => 'Footer Finanzas',
        'footer-spotlight' => 'Footer Spotlight',
        'footer-otras-publicaciones' => 'Footer Otras Publicaciones'
    ) );
}
```

But the main nav menu is not working is displaying one of the footer menus and this is driving me crazy, any idea guys what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have `menu` two times as parameter, you probably want:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'main', 'menu' => 'menu_center' ));
```

---

*Edit:*

From your comments I'm getting that you're missing some information about the whole topic, e.g. the difference between the description and the name of a menu. To resolve this you really should just read the according documentation thoroughly:

- [WordPress Menu User Guide](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)
- [Appearance Menus Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen)
- [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

  - [register_nav_menus()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus)
  - [register_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for the response, in your example you have theme_location, should I leave that like you suggested?

Comment: One thing I noticed is this, when I try to load the new theme and add the new menus it keeps the old menus from the old theme

Comment: You don't need `theme_location`, I was just assuming this might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, then, sorry but this should be like wp_nav_menu( array('Main Nav' => 'main', 'menu' => 'menu_center' ));?

Comment: Sorry mate, I actually can't see the difference, too late. Have you read [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) @Arturo

Comment: @Arturo Now I see it, you can't use it like you suggested in your last comment, because you're using »Main Nav« as parameter, which can't work. Besides that, take a look at the register_nav_menu/register_nav_menus documentation and you will realize that they register location and description.

Comment: Hi Ialocin, thanks for your message, one question, why this can't work on my functions document? 

'main' => 'Main Nav',